# Calling a Method in Swift Unit Tests

Tags: objective-c, swift, unit-testing, objective-c-category

My previous approach in Objective-C for unit testing was like following:

- Calling a public method: no problem
- Calling a private method: create a category of that class in your unit test file and put the signature of the private method into this category

Currently, I have the following:

- Class developed in ObjC
- Protocol developed in Swift
- Unit tests for that class developed in Swift

The class conforms (directly, in its public interface (.h)) to that protocol. I have a class instance in my unit tests but somehow I can not invoke a method declared in the protocol over that instance.

Now, the old Category solution does not work with Extensions. When I put some method signature in the extension I get that error saying "Function body expected in declaration".

How can I call the functions with Swift in the best way?

PS: I do not want to declare the method again in the public interface of the class, that is an ugly solution.

Comment: Did you try to import the module with `@testable import <Module>` in you Swift test class?  It's supposed to do exactly what you want, that is to "open" access to private stuff of the tested class to the test without forcing you to change the visibility.  This is [what they say](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html): _"Use @testable import {ModuleName} in your test source code to make all public and internal routines usable by XCTest targets, but not by other framework and app targets."_

Comment: Remember; @testable only makes protected members available to tests, private methods, functions and parameters are still unavailable.

Comment: That does not work guys.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation on "Writing Tests with Swift" [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html):

> Xcode provides a two-part solution to this problem:
>
> When you set the *Enable Testability build setting to Yes*, which is
>   true by default for test builds in new projects, Xcode includes the
>   -enable-testing flag during compilation. This makes the Swift entities declared in the compiled module eligible for a higher level of access.
>   When you *add the @testable attribute to an import statement for a
>   module compiled with testing enabled*, you activate the elevated access
>   for that module in that scope. Classes and class members marked as
>   internal or public behave as if they were marked open. Other entities
>   marked as internal act as if they were declared public.

Here is also the example (for MySwiftApp)

- Class built for a target with *Enable Testability* set to *yes*

  ```
  import Cocoa
  @NSApplicationMain

  class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
      @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
      func foo() {

      println("Hello, World!")
      }
  }
  ```
- Unit test class

  ```
  // Importing XCTest because of XCTestCase
  import XCTest

  // Importing AppKit because of NSApplication
  import AppKit

  // Importing MySwiftApp because of AppDelegate
  @testable import MySwiftApp

  class MySwiftAppTests: XCTestCase {
      func testExample() {
          let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
          appDelegate.foo()
      }
  }
  ```

Also see the important Note

> Note: @testable provides access only for internal functions;
>   file-private and private declarations are not visible outside of their
>   usual scope when using @testable.